# Accessing Excel object methods from Matlab through COM, how to skip optional positional arguments?

Tags: matlab, com, excel-interop

I am using the Component Ojbect Model (COM) interface to Excel.  The following is a protoype of a method that accepts both positional and named arguments, all of which are optional [1].

> expression.Add (SourceType, Source, LinkSource, XlListObjectHasHeaders, Destination, TableStyleName)
>
> expression A variable that represents a ListObjects object.

The above is the "Add" method in class ListObject.  If I invoke it from VBA, I can use named arguments to specify a subset of the arguments in the prototype.

Is there any way to do this via COM from Matlab?  From all that I've found online, positional arguments are used to invoke methods via COM.

**NOTES**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add

Comment: "Is there any way to do this via COM?" yes, since VBA is itself using COM. Don't know how to do this from Matlab though.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing that out.  I clarified in the question that I'm seeking to do this from Matlab.

Comment: For COM all parameters are the same. Dispatch interfaces do support optional parameters, but you still need to provide all the parameters, optional ones should contain special variant value, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140129-00/?p=1933

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by all COM parameters being the same?  I looked at the page you cited, but it's not clear how to do that from Matlab.  I see that I'm not the only one experiencing this (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278376/whats-the-matlab-equivalent-of-null-when-its-calling-com-activex-methods)). This question is a few months behind me, but when I get back into the work again, I'll experiment with some of suggestions there.